# Several item templates in one listbox in mvvmcross Android

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross, itemtemplate

I use MvvmCross framework.
I want to use different item templates in one listview depending on ViewModel type.
For example I have the list of AnimalViewModels. And I want KittenViewModel and PuppyViewModel look different.

I found out how to do this in iOS and WP7. How to implement this in Android.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

A few of the samples show how to use cell type selection. See:

- polymorphic lists in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections
- grouped lists in the session list views in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference