# MvvmCross : dynamic item template selection for MvxListView

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, mvvmcross, itemtemplate, itemtemplateselector

If I have a view with the following MvxListView definition:

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_marginTop="10px"
    android:textFilterEnabled="true"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Data; ItemClick LaunchCapabilityViewCmd"
    local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/itemtemplate1" />
```

Instead of hard coding MvxItemTemplate to itemtemplate1, it it possible to dynamically set this based on the type of data I want to display in this view?  I am looking for similar functionality to WPF's DateTemplateSelector.

TIA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use a custom adapter to do this.

A few of the samples show how to use cell type selection. See:

- polymorphic lists in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Working%20With%20Collections
- grouped lists in the session list views in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference

e.g. from [PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Working%20With%20Collections/Collections.Droid/Views/PolymorphicListItemTypesView.cs)

```
        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object source, int templateId)
        {
            if (source is Kitten)
                templateId = Resource.Layout.ListItem_Kitten;
            else if (source is Dog)
                templateId = Resource.Layout.ListItem_Dog;

            return base.GetBindableView(convertView, source, templateId);
        }
```

For Android, there is also an optimisation which should be added to the existing polymorphic adapter samples - to include use of `GetItemViewType` for better `convertView` reuse - see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/issues/333

This questions is linked to:

- [Several item templates in one listbox in mvvmcross Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341590/several-item-templates-in-one-listbox-in-mvvmcross-android)
- [getViewTypeCount and getItemViewType methods of ArrayAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter)

Comment: I've checked the sample, and it contains the optimizations. So you can close the issue :)